# How to access reserved keywords in JSON attributes?

Tags: ballerina

I was trying this sample code.

```
string s = "{\"resource\":\"b\", \"aa\":\"aa\"}";
public function main() {
    json j2 = checkpanic value:fromJsonString(s);
    io:println(j2.aa);
    io:println(j2.resource);
}
```

But it gives the following error

```
ERROR [app.bal:(12:19,12:27)] invalid token 'resource'
ERROR [app.bal:(12:19,12:19)] missing identifier
error: compilation contains errors
```

It seems that "resource" is a reserved token, but j2.aa works without an issue. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single quotes to escape reserved keywords: as `j2.'resource`

For more information, you can refer to: [Ballerina Identifiers](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/identifiers/)

Answer (score 1):

In Ballerina language, "resource" is a reserved keyword. The problem is when you're trying to access a field named "resource" in a JSON object using the field-access expression.

To access a JSON field that has a name that is a reserved keyword (or has special characters), you can use the string-based field access.

By using the string-based field access, e.g., `j2["resource"]`, you can avoid the error.

I revised your code, and it's here:

```py
string s = "{\"resource\":\"b\", \"aa\":\"aa\"}";

public function main() {
    json j2 = checkpanic value:fromJsonString(s);
    io:println(j2["aa"]);
    io:println(j2["resource"]);
}
```

Also you can  cast the `json` variable to a `map` and then access its values. This can be particularly useful if you're consistently working with JSON objects and don't want to use string-based access throughout your code.

You can do it like this:

```py
string s = "{\"resource\":\"b\", \"aa\":\"aa\"}";

public function main() {
    json j2 = checkpanic value:fromJsonString(s);
    
    map<json> j2Map = <map<json>> j2;

    io:println(j2Map["aa"]);
    io:println(j2Map["resource"]);
}
```

With this approach, you cast the `json` type to a `map<json>` type, allowing you to utilize map-based access for any key, even if it's a reserved keyword in Ballerina.

Answer (score 0):

Ballerina is a statically typed language. When it comes to json type where the lax static typing can be applied. In lax typing, the type checking will happen at runtime.

In lax typing you can use the dot operator (.) for field access.
Lax typing also supports optional field access using (?.) operator. In here let say there may or may not be a field named `key` in the json. If a value is not present it will return a `()` value.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() returns error? {
   json j = {
        'resource: "A",
        value: 10,
        arr: [
            1, "2", "3"
        ]
    };
    check laxTypingExample(j);
}

function laxTypingExample(json j) returns error? {
    string 'resource = check j.'resource;
    io:println('resource);

    int value = check j.value;
    io:println(value);

    json arr = check j.arr;
    if arr is json[] {
        io:println(arr);
    }

    int? optionalKey = check j?.'key;
    io:println(optionalKey);
}
```

Comment: If you are interested learn more about the lax typing you can read this medium article. [link](https://medium.com/ballerina-techblog/ballerinas-json-type-and-lax-static-typing-3b952f6add01#:~:text=Ballerina%20is%20a%20statically%20typed,are%20defined%20to%20be%20lax.)